# Surface treatment and current density: electrodeposition of Cd and Ag

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm currently working on a cadmium and silver electrodeposition project.

Let me explain:

I'm doing electrolytic surface treatment on low-alloy steels as well as stainless steels. At present, we have no mathematical way of defining the intensity and therefore the current density to be applied to the bath, as each colleague does this according to their own experience.

I'd like to set up a calculation program or some other tool that would enable us to work in the same way, and make it easier to train newcomers.

I've tried looking for mathematical relationships (Faraday's law, etc.), but it's complicated because there are too many parameters.

Does anyone know anything about this? I need some light!

Thanks in advance for your comments

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? It seems very unclear what the actual problem is. You have some deposition setup and you do not know what current you apply, or rather the current density you apply? Current density is as simple as current divided by area. If you can measure the area of your electrode and look at your power source what current it applies you can simply calculate current density.